# missing error handler on 'socket'. node.js / socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I get this error when i try to receive data from my client which is a video time of a video that updates every second or so. i think the error is happening on the client receive part but im not sure how to fix it.

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha7tr.png)

this is my server code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

switch(path){
    case '/':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write('hello world');
        response.end();
        break;
    case '/index.html':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                response.end();
            }
            else{
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.end();
            }
        });
        break;
        case '/main.js':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                response.end();
            }
            else{
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.end();
            }
        });
        break;
        case '/remote-clock.js':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                response.end();
            }
            else{
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.end();
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
        response.end();
        break;
}
});

server.listen(25565);

io.listen(server);


var listener = io.listen(server);

listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  //send data to client
  setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
  }, 1000);

  //recieve client data
  socket.on('client_data', function(data){
    process.stdout.write(data.letter);
 });
});
```

this client code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>


             <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

            padding: 0px;
            margin: 5%;
            width: 90%;
        }

        video {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #volume {
            width: 70%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay>
        <source src="http://googledrive.com/host/0B-5FC9-wtiZzbTJFQnljdzNDdEE" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://googledrive.com/host/0B-5FC9-wtiZzbTJFQnljdzNDdEE" type="video/webm"/>
    </video>
    <div>
        <label>Volume: </label><input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.0001" value="1" id="volume"/>
        <button id="mute">Unmute</button>
        <button id="play">Play</button>

    </div>
    <div>Server Time: <span id="clock"></span></div>
    <div>Video Time: <span id="video-time"></span></div>
    <article>
        <h1>Synchronized Video Player</h1>
        <p><a href="" target="_blank">Open this page</a> in another browser window, even on another device, and the videos should be synchronized.</p>

    </article>


      <script>
      var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('date', function(data){
    $('#date').text(data.date);
  });


   </script>
   <div id="date"></div>
  <textarea id="text"></textarea>


        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js">     </script>

        <script src="remote-clock.js"></script>
         <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

my main.js code is :

```
(function (window) {
var CLOCK_PORT = 5001,
    EPSILON = -1 / 15,
    DURATION = 149.619,

    maxOffset = 1 / 30,
    video = document.getElementById('video'),
    clock = document.getElementById('clock'),
    videoTime = document.getElementById('video-time'),
    volume = document.getElementById('volume'),
    muted = document.getElementById('muted'),

    targetTime = 0,
    serverUrl,
    remoteClock,
    durationInMilliseconds,
    timeout,
    retries = 0,

    isBuffered;

function updateClockDisplay() {

    clock.textContent = (new Date(remoteClock.time())).toTimeString();
    videoTime.textContent = (video.currentTime).toFixed(2);
    requestAnimationFrame(updateClockDisplay);

  socket.emit('client_data', {'letter': videoTime});
  console.log(video.currentTime);


}

function checkAgain(delay) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(checkSync, delay);
}

function checkSync(evt) {
    var currentTime,
        current,
        currentBuffered,
        targetBuffered,
        targetDiff,
        currentDiff,
        skip;

    //currentTime is the time we should be at NOW
    currentTime = (remoteClock.time() % durationInMilliseconds) / 1000;

    //targetTime is the time we're seeking to and want to catch up to later
    //it's a little bit ahead of where we are so we can take time to buffer
    targetTime = Math.max(targetTime, currentTime);

    currentDiff = currentTime - video.currentTime;

    current = currentDiff > EPSILON && currentDiff < maxOffset;
    targetBuffered = isBuffered(targetTime);
    currentBuffered = isBuffered(currentTime) && isBuffered(currentTime + 2);

    if (currentBuffered && current) {
        video.play();
        retries = Math.min(2, retries);
        checkAgain(2000);
        return;
    }

    //we missed our window, so seek ahead and try again
    if (currentDiff >= EPSILON && video.readyState < 2 || currentDiff > 1) {
        skip = Math.pow(2, Math.min(4, Math.max(retries, 1)));
        targetTime = (currentTime + skip) % DURATION;
        video.pause();
        video.currentTime = targetTime;
        retries++;
        maxOffset = Math.max(maxOffset, retries * 0.1);
        checkAgain(1000);
        return;
    }

    //we haven't caught up yet, so give it a little more time to buffer and check in again
    targetDiff = targetTime - currentTime;
    checkAgain(targetDiff * 500);
}

function stateUpdate(evt) {
    if (!video.duration) {
        console.log('No video duration yet');
        video.pause();
        return;
    }

    console.log('video metadata', video.duration, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    durationInMilliseconds = Math.round(DURATION * 1000);
    if (remoteClock.accuracy() > 100) {
        return;
    }

    checkSync(evt || 'clock update');
}

function timeBuffered(time) {
    var i;
    if (!video.buffered) {
        return true;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < video.buffered.length; i++) {
        if (video.buffered.start(i) > time) {
            return false;
        }
        if (video.buffered.end(i) >= time) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



serverUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + ':' + CLOCK_PORT + '/time-server';
remoteClock = new RemoteClock(serverUrl, stateUpdate);



video.muted = true;
video.addEventListener('durationchange', stateUpdate, false);
//video.addEventListener('waiting', stateUpdate, false);
//video.addEventListener('seeked', stateUpdate, false);
video.addEventListener('volumechange', function () {
    volume.value = video.volume;
    if (video.muted) {
        mute.textContent = 'Unmute';
    } else {
        mute.textContent = 'Mute';
    }
});
mute.addEventListener('click', function () {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
});
volume.addEventListener('input', function () {
    video.volume = volume.value;
});



play.addEventListener('click', function () {


    if (video.paused) {
        play.textContent = 'Play';
        video.play(); 
    } else {
        play.textContent = 'Pause';
        video.pause();
    }
});









window.addEventListener('touchstart', function touchstart(evt) {
    video.load();
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchstart, true);
}, true);
updateClockDisplay();
}(this));
```

Comment: Do you have the client code?

Comment: @afuous i just added some more of the client side code hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is appearing on line 80, this line:

```
process.stdout.write(data.letter);
```

If you open up an interactive node session and type

```
process.stdout.write({a: "b"});
```

it gives an error about invalid data saying that you cannot pass an object to `process.stdout.write`, only a string or buffer. You are sending `{'letter': videoTime}` to the server, and `videoTime` refers to an HTML element, which is an object. You are typing to write the HTML element to the console. If what you want to pass to the server is the video time and not the HTML element that holds the video time, you can change the client code to

```
{'letter': videoTime.textContent}
```